# Audio equalizer using FFmpeg or OpenAL

Tags: c++, audio, signal-processing, fft, equalizer

I'm developing audio player using FFmpeg and OpenAL libraries. I want to add audio equaliqer to my app, but I don't know how to do it. 
I tried to use OpenAL Equalizer effect extension, but I'm getting "Undefined value" error while initializing it.
I found out that I can use Fast Fourier Transformation for creating equalizer. FFmpeg providing FFT functions, but I don't know how to use them with audio samples.
Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Many questions and answers on this subject already - see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814065/how-to-modify-fft-result-to-equalize-a-music-sample, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794692/how-equalize-on-c-after-fft and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929401/dsp-filtering-in-the-frequency-domain-via-fft

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed some errors in OpenAL to enable equalizer effect and then it works fine.